# Calling function with argument in a javascript object

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I want to print any object. I hope you understand, what i want. I am new. Below is my code,

```
function abhi(x)
{
    var abhi = new Object();
    abhi.first_name = "abhijit";
    abhi.last_name = "Das";
    abhi.age = 22;
    document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = abhi.x ;
}
</script>
<p id="name"></p>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Name" onclick="abhi(age)"/>
</body>
```

Comment: Instead of document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = abhi.x ;, use document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = x ;

Answer (score 3):

In HTML you need to pass a string:

```
onclick="abhi('age')"
```

If `age` is a variable containing `"age"`, it's OK.

Then you can use it in the script like this:

```
document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = abhi[x];
```

You can read more about the bracket notation and objects at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Objects_and_properties).

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to use square bracket notation to access properties of objects by passing a string.

```
document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = abhi[x];
...
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Name" onclick="abhi('age')"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use this line

```
document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = abhi[x] ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getAbhi(x) {

    var abhi = {
        first_name: "abhijit",
        last_name: "Das",
        age: 22
    };

    document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = abhi[x];
}
</script>

<p id="name"></p>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Name" onclick="getAbhi('age')" />
```

http://jsfiddle.net/samliew/H7Zs9/7/